# how to attach pdf as part of soap UI request using Mtom

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using soap, as part of request i am attaching a pdf file. In SOPAUI i have attached pdf file using following link [SOAPUI DOC](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/adding-headers-and-attachments.html) and enabled mtom property to ture as per guidence.

problem is, it is not even hitting the server end point before itself i am getting error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Draft//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error 500--Internal Server Error</TITLE>
<META NAME="GENERATOR" CONTENT="WebLogic Server">
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="white">
<FONT FACE=Helvetica><BR CLEAR=all>
<TABLE border=0 cellspacing=5><TR><TD><BR CLEAR=all>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica" COLOR="black" SIZE="3"><H2>Error 500--Internal Server Error</H2>
</FONT></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE border=0 width=100% cellpadding=10><TR><TD VALIGN=top WIDTH=100% BGCOLOR=white><FONT FACE="Courier New"><pre>java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.saaj.TextImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement
    at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.derefMTOMAttachments(SOAPMessageImpl.java:279)
    at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.constructMessage(SOAPMessageImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPMessageImpl.<init>(SOAPMessageImpl.java:151)
    at weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:63)
    at weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:182)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:86)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3717)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
</pre></FONT></TD></TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

in SOAPUI, set the Strip Whitespaces toggle to true

Answer (score 0):

In SOAP-UI I had to change the Request Property "Disable multiparts" to "false". In the linked documentation in the original question, it is shown as set to "true"